# $facebook->getUser() returns a userid after logout

Tags: php, facebook-login

How do I check if the user is really loggedin? `$facebook->getUser()` still returns an ID after logout. Do I need to do something like `$facebook->api('/me')` just to check if the user is "really" logged in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, FB PHP SDK in my opinion is quite tricky because it relies on a cookie sent from Facebook when you are logging into the Facebook. This cookie is not deleted whilst logging out. Because of that in below code the variable $uid could store a proper user facebook id:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
```

So, as far as I know, call `$facebook->api('/me');` will tell the truth whether the user is logged in or not.

```
try {
   $facebook->api('/me');
   /* user is really logged into FB */
} catch (Exception $e) {
   /* user is not currently logged into the FB */
}
```

I use above code in my production application and it works well.

Comment: Wonder why facebook doesnt remove the cookie?

Comment: @jiewmeng, cookie is placed on your domain Facebook doesn't have control on it other than JS-SDK (or other SDK) you use. They actually remove the cookie if they can (by JS-SDK at least), but if user logs out while not interacting with your application/site cookie your responsibility.

Comment: Exactly, so in fact I use both PHP and JS Facebook SDK so as to get full functionality of Facebook API.

Comment: I noticed interesting behavior (bug?). When the user logs off from the browser, and a call to getUser made to check on server (using PHP-SDK), it returns the userid first time it's called, but 2nd time it's called it returns zero! One can theoretically call getUser twice and see if user is logged on but the best bet is to call /me and check !

Answer (score 2):

[getLoginStatusUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/) should do the trick.
I think that if you ask for offline_perms than you have access to user_id and so on. I don't know if you did, but most likely that should be the problem

Comment: Erm I am new to FB development, I just tried the PHP SDK demo. Where do I look to see the permissions I asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the method detailed in the [Facebook PHP SDK Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/)?

```
$params = array(
  'ok_session' => 'https://www.myapp.com/',
  'no_user' => 'https://www.myapp.com/no_user',
  'no_session' => 'https://www.myapp.com/no_session',
);

$next_url = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params);
```

> Returns a URL based on the user’s login status on Facebook. You can
>   get a different URL depending on whether the user is logged in, not
>   connected, or logged out of Facebook.

Comment: Ok, but got a URL, when logged out, I have something like `...no_session=0&no_user=0&ok_session=1...` ... which means I'm logged in anyway. When I go facebook.com I am not logged in ...